# Jquery Slide Menu Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a slide in/out nav menu with jquery but I ran into a problem. If I click the 'fa-bars' icon, and only that, everything works smoothly. However, when I click the 'fa-times' icon to close the nav menu (which I want it to do) it works as desired but the 'fa-bars' icon is no longer clickable in order to re-open the menu. I know it has something to do with my JS code but I just can't crack it.

```css
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0;
}

li {
font-size: 30px;
color: black;
}

.fa-bars {
position: static;
left: 100px;
top: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-bars:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-times {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-times:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

nav {
background-color: lightslategrey;
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 1;
transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.active-nav {
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.closed-nav {
transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

<nav>
    
    <ul>
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
        <li>New TO</li>
        <li>Street TO</li>
        <li>Classy TO</li>
        <li>Athletic TO</li>
    </ul>

</nav>

JS:

$(function () {

$('.fa-bars').click(function () {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active-nav');
});

$('.fa-times').click(function() {
    $('.active-nav').toggleClass('closed-nav');
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sdvb45nj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handlers are being called correctly but you are toggling the wrong class, The following fixes the problem.

```
$('.fa-bars').click(function () {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active-nav');
});

$('.fa-times').click(function() {
    $('.active-nav').toggleClass('active-nav');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem starts when clicking the close button

`$('.active-nav').toggleClass('closed-nav');`

With the above code you will add `closed-nav` to the `nav` which will close ... after that you use

```
$('nav').toggleClass('active-nav');
```

With the above code you remove `active-nav` from `nav` while `closed-nav` still on

so you need to remove the `closed-nav` class and add `active-nav` ..

To solve that you can use

```
$('nav').removeClass('closed-nav').addClass('active-nav');
```

instead of

```
$('nav').toggleClass('active-nav');
```

```js
$(function () {
    
    $('.fa-bars').click(function () {
        $('nav').removeClass('closed-nav').addClass('active-nav');
    });
    
    $('.fa-times').click(function() {
        $('.active-nav').toggleClass('closed-nav');
    });
    
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
}

.fa-bars {
    position: static;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-bars:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-times {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-times:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

nav {
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.active-nav {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.closed-nav {
    transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    
    <nav>
        
        <ul>
            <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
            <li>New TO</li>
            <li>Street TO</li>
            <li>Classy TO</li>
            <li>Athletic TO</li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```